# find the .cnf file used by the running mysql instance

Tags: mysql-5.7

I wanted tho know the .cnf file read by my running mysql instance. I used to look at ps command.

ps -ef | grep mysql

10801 ?        Ssl    0:27 /usr/sbin/mysqld --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/my.cnf --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

But in redhat 7 and 8 i am not able to see a detailed output.

ps ax | grep mysqld

798 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

Is there a way to get details via ps command or any other way to check which conf file is being used by my mysql instance.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you set a particular non-default setting in this? Does `show global variables like 'variable_name'` as a SQL query show the same result? Where was the file added? What sections like `[mysqld]` did it have? What is at the top of `mysqld --help --verbose` as far as files/sections it reads?

Comment: Its a default installation done through package manager, so i know the /etc/my.cnf is the conf file that is being used.  mysqld --help --verbose lists out the order in which files will be read while the mysql starts (Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
(/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf) . What if i started mysqld --defaults-file = /data/mysql/my.cnf --user = mysql & . How will i find which conf file my running mysqld used.

Comment: In the process list you can see which file (or revert looking at the defaults). If by a SQL mechanism, this isn't exposed.

Comment: @danblack : ya thats what i am expecting, that is the case till redhat 6. Now in redhat 7 , it is not giving a detailed output.                                                                                               ps -ef | grep mysqld

798 ? Sl 0:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

Comment: However the real question is, why does it matter? What are you trying to acheive?

Comment: @danblack : I am doing an automation stuff. through ansible i wanted to fetch a copy of actual my.cnf that is being used in respective target host to my ansible host and do analysis there. We cannot say /etc/my.cnf is the standard location for all my targets.. It varies in some hosts.Tats d reason i am looking for exact shell command so that i can pass it through ansible.